# Is "square up" a natural expression in conversational English?

Tags: american-english

**"Square up"**

**To pay the balance of what is owed to someone.**

> You get our jackets while I go **square up** with the bartender.
>
> Brian and I need to **square up** for those plane tickets soon—I hate
>   owing someone money.

Would I be able to say this in a normal conversation in English without sounding too weird?

Comment: I'm not American, so I can't say if this usage is correct there, but here it sounds like your about to have an all out brawl with  the bartender, then beat Brian to a pulp so he doesn't ask you  for his money again.

Answer (score 2):

The sentences are OK and natural. Take care with the preposition. You square up **to** someone you are ready to fight, and square up **with** someone you owe money to, or **for** something you have received but are yet to pay for.

Comment: So it is totally natural to say that?

Comment: Yes. My answer was intended to state that.